# defining or automatically setting required fields for a type of class

Tags: python, class, oop, abstract-class, subclass

I have a range of derived classes "ChildA", "ChildB", etc... that all inherit from a Base class "Parent".

The purpose of Parent is to implement a common method for executing code in Child classes. Inside this method is a condition based on the child instance's 'status'.

```
class Parent:
    def process(self):
        try:
            self.run()
        except:
            assert self.status == 'ok'

class ChildA(Parent):
    def run(self):
        ...
```

I want save the future developers Child classes from unpleasant surprises.

I feel like the solution would come in the form of an AbstractClass, but I haven't (fully) grasped the concept yet. Or rather, I get the concept, but not how to apply it.

Otherwise I can:

- specify the requirement for a 'status' field in doc.

  - I'd much prefer a strict and organic enforcement mean.
- add `__init__(self): self.status = None` to the Parent, and require (via documentation once again), all Child classes to use
  super() to call the Parent's init function.

  - looks overcomplicated for a Base init method that only initialises one field, but willing to use that if that's the Pythonic way to do it.
- check for a .status field at the beginning of Parent.process()

  - Does the job in one line but too hacky.

What do you recommend?

Running Python 3.5

Comment: The "right" solution always depend on the concrete use cases and target audience - but in all cases you want to clearly document your API and what's expected from child classes.

Comment: One thing quite *wrong*  there is the use of an undiscriminated `except`  clause: always specify the errors you are expecting  - or at least log whichever error you got.

Comment: Worth noting! The actual line of code is `except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:`.

Answer (score 0):

I think beeing explicit and call super is probably the best way to go.
But you could also consider using a property in the Parent class:

```
class Parent(object):

    def process(self):
        try:
            self.run()
        except Exception, e:
            assert self.status == 'ok'

    def get_status(self):
        try:
            return self._status
        except AttributeError:
            print "oops: child class did not initialize status"
            return "ok"

    def set_status(self, status):
        self._status = status

    status = property(get_status, set_status)

class BadChild(Parent):
    def run(self):
        print "run bad"
        self.status

class GoodChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = "ok"

    def run(self):
        print "run good"
        self.status
```

And the test:

```
bad = BadChild()
good = GoodChild()

good.process()
bad.process()
```